# mySQL 8 UUID_TO_BIN and BIN_TO_UUID with sailsjs

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline, mysql-8.0

all!

I'm writing an API backend, where I'd like to use my primary keys in mysql8 as Binary(16) to saving uuids.
I know that mySQL8 provide the functions UUID_TO_BIN and BIN_TO_UUID. 
My question is, how can I set up my model, using Sailsjs and waterline, to represent my primary keys as (string) uuids in the API while they are binary(16) in the database? 
There is any way to do it in my model, without using native queries?

Thanks :)